# ImageId not assign for variable in angular 11

Tags: angular

I tried to assign imageId to a variable but it's not assigned. In the console log, it's showing **undefined**. below is my code which I tried. I can able to log my object in the console log.

[Object result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFelY.png)

```
imageId: number;

this.imageService.getImage(this.productId).subscribe(m => {
  this.imageData = m;
  this.imageId = this.imageData.Id;
  console.log(m);
  console.log('ImageId ' + this.imageId);
});
```

Comment: Is your response object (m) is array of objects ?

Comment: Yes. I'm try to get imageId from that object

Comment: If it is an array, you need to get the first (or whatever you need) result: `m[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in the attachment console , your response is array of object.
you cannot get directly id property from array object. Need to specify index. Try this

```
  this.imageData = m;
  this.imageId = this.imageData[0].Id;
  console.log(m);
  console.log('ImageId ' + this.imageId);
```